# wp7, silverlight, Why event fires twice?

Tags: silverlight, events, windows-phone-7

In this case when user click some UIElement I want this element yo be surrounded by dashed border. If there is some other object surrounded then this code removes it first.

Everything is fine but "private void activateElem" fires twice and I have no idea why. Maybe somebody can help, I really have no more ideas.

Anybody knows some ideas to debug issues like this? Maybe there is some way to print out all events queue. There is silverlight spy but I think it doesn't work for windows phone 7.

My code:

```
 public class ManipulationEngine
{
    private Canvas sheet;
    private static FrameworkElement current_active_element;

    public ManipulationEngine(Canvas sheet)
    {
        this.sheet = sheet;

        foreach (FrameworkElement elem in sheet.Children)
        {
            elem.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(activateElem);
        }

    }

    private void activateElem(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement elem = sender as FrameworkElement;

        if (current_active_element != null)
        {
            desactivateElem();
        }

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        Rectangle recentagle = new Rectangle();

        grid.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)elem.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty) - 10);
        grid.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)elem.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty) - 10);

        DoubleCollection stroke = new DoubleCollection();
        stroke.Add(4);
        stroke.Add(2);
        recentagle.StrokeDashArray = stroke;

        grid.Children.Add(recentagle);
        sheet.Children.Remove(elem);
        elem.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        grid.Children.Add(elem);
        sheet.Children.Add(grid);

        current_active_element = elem;
    }



    private void desactivateElem()
    {
        if (current_active_element != null)
        {
            Grid grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current_active_element) as Grid;

            grid.Children.Remove(current_active_element);
            sheet.Children.Remove(grid);

            current_active_element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)grid.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty) + 10);
            current_active_element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)grid.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty) + 10);
            current_active_element.Margin = new Thickness(0);

            sheet.Children.Add(current_active_element);

            current_active_element = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I have found the solution. When I click on FrameworkElement  then event fires. After this I remove the FrameworkElement from Canvas and I add it into grid and than I add grid back To Canvas. So the solution is: "e.Handled = true;". It works now :)

So Afterwards the FrameworkElement is deeper in the tree and somehow it fires again.

Comment: Add that as an answer and accept it in a couple of days. It will provide the solution should anyone else experience the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really advise looking into the Parts and States model. You may be able to do this with a button, or perhaps a radio button.

Usually if you're coding changes to the visual tree, you're not doing it right.

Karen Corby dealt with this very clearly at MIX08, take a look!

http://archive.visitmix.com/blogs/2008Sessions/T20/

Luke